# discord.py - check multiple guilds id

Tags: python, discord.py

Okay so I'm trying to make a command that is only available for specific guilds.

Here's The code.

If I add multiple guild IDs then every guild can use this command.

```py
async def is_guild(ctx):
    return ctx.guild.id == someguildidhere, someguildidhere

@client.command()
@commands.check(is_guild)
async def checkispremium(ctx):
    await ctx.send("Guild owns lifetime premium.")

@checkispremium.error
async def checkispremium(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.CheckFailure):
        await ctx.send("Guild doesn't owns premium ")
```

However when I add only one guild ID then everything works fine. Only the specific guild can use the command and others will get error.

```
async def is_guild(ctx):
    return ctx.guild.id == someguildidhere

@client.command()
@commands.check(is_guild)
async def checkispremium(ctx):
    await ctx.send("Guild owns lifetime premium.")

@checkispremium.error
async def checkispremium(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.CheckFailure):
        await ctx.send("Guild doesn't owns premium")
```

Anyone know how can I have multiple guild IDs, I tried looking at discordpy-rewrite docs, but looks like nothing is there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
async def is_guild(ctx):
    return ctx.guild.id in [someguildidhere, someguildidhere, ...]
```